# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 500

Tags: system-installation, laptop, lenovo

How can I install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 500 Laptop?
Is there a better way than a virtual machine?
I have to use Ubuntu for my work.